# Column space, Row space, Null space, rank

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

May I have some help here with concepts with column space, row space, null space and rank?
If I just have the answers for the questions below, it would help so much with my understanding of linear algebra. Thank you in advance.

1. Is the dimension of the null space of matrix A plus the dimension of the row space of the matrix A equal to n? (The matrix A is some arbitrary m*n matrix.)
2. Is the pivot columns of matrix A equal to the pivot rows of transpose of matrix A? If this is true, is the column space of transpose of matrix A equal to the row space of matrix A?
3. What is the point of differentiating between row space and column space? What is the use of row space when there already is the concept of column space? Is this just about switching perspectives?
4. Row space is the linear combination of independent row vectors. These row vectors are the basis vectors of the row space. Column space is the linear combination of independent column vectors. These column vectors are the basis vectors of the column space. I am wondering "What is the relationship between the basis vectors of column space and the basis vectors of row space?"

Comment: 2. makes no sense. Do you mean if the number of pivot columns is equal for $A$ and $A^t$?

Comment: Hello. SIr. Thank you for the answer, and the comment. It took me some time to process your answer.
For Question 2, I was trying to ask if the pivot columns of matrix is the same as the pivot rows of its transpose matrix.

Comment: what does that mean? If the matrix is $m\times n$, then your dimensions are different and the answer is immediately "no".